# Is the bird killing in The Prestige based on historical reality?

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-prestige

In [The Prestige (2006)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige_(film)), there is a magic trick in which [a bird is made to disappear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKL5B22MueU) and it is revealed that the bird is secretly killed by crushing it flat to make it "disappear". Is this trick from real history, or was it invented for the book/movie.

Comment: My understanding of The Prestige is guy #1 is doing it with a single live bird and guy #2 can't figure out how and decides that crushing birds to make the illusion is worth it.

Comment: @Joshua ... that's not my take on it at all.  I think the trick with the cage on the table is meant to be "well known" and not particularly innovative (and yes results in a dead bird per time it is shown).  The version that Cutter invents has a hand-held cage, but still crushes the bird.  We are never shown the trick where the bird survives.

Comment: When Cutter is walking Angier through the modified (hand-held) version of the trick, he ties a string to the bird's leg which pulls it out through the side of the cage as it's retracted into the apparatus concealed in Angier's sleeves.  During this walk-through, the (apparently same) live bird is then produced from behind Cutter's back.  I believe on stage the bird does die, but only because Borden (in disguise) sabotages it and causes it to misfire.

Comment: @iandotkelly: That doesn't disprove Joshua's point that it was _initially_ harmless to the bird, but then someone decided to just brute force it by killing birds, and it becoming popular, thus making it "well known and not particularly innovative" over time. This is remniscent of how urban legends are often born: the first one to tell the story know's it's a lie, but retellers thought it was true, eventually turning the tale into a "true story".

Comment: @Flater ... I don't understand.  Where does the movie show "guy #1" doing it with a single live bird and "guy #2" can't figure out how?  As far as I can see Borden is involved with another magician who does it traditionally with a table in one scene (and lies to the kid about the bird being fine) and Angier does an updated trick that doesn't use a table.  Each trick kills a bird, which is why they have a large stock of canaries.  I don't recall any indication that it was ever initially harmless (unless I missed something).

Comment: @iandotkelly: Just watched it... when Cutter demonstrates his version to Angier, it is clearly shown ("this is the best part") that the bird survives. This is also emphasized by the dialogue that follows where Angier is surprised he didn't have 'to get his hands dirty' after all. I interpret the cage thing as foreshadowing Borden and Angier's different approaches to magic. Borden uses simple techniques, whereas Angier uses technology to actually produce the desired effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I did a little research on this question and it appears that the trick MIGHT kill the canary, or might not, but inevitably did result in a lot of bird deaths. Here is the notice:

> The vanishing bird trick (which, I regret to say, kills a great number
>   of canaries) is performed by means of accessories in which the costume
>   plays a part. The bird cage itself is made to collapse into a cigar
>   shaped tube. The centre of the cigar shape is naturally fatter than
>   the ends, and, if the bird is fortunate, it is secreted there and may
>   come out of the ordeal alive. Should, however, the bird get at either
>   end it is crushed to death, or should the legs get through the bars
>   they are almost certain to be broken. A conjurer once told me he had
>   done the trick 200 times with one bird, but I should very much doubt
>   it.
>
> What happens is this. The bird cage is rapidly hooked to the end
>   of a piece of whipcord, which passes up the sleeve and across the body
>   of the performer, and then down the other sleeve, where it is tied to
>   the wrist. It will thus be seen that the cord is considerably shorter
>   than will be required to stretch from each end of the arms if they are
>   extended. The cage, being in the performer's hand, is rapidly
>   compressed and made to assume its cigar shaped form, and is dragged up
>   the arm at lightning speed by the simple process of extending the two
>   arms.
>
> This very simple trick has puzzled millions of people. It is
>   performed so rapidly that even if you closely watch the conjurer I
>   doubt if you will know what he is doing. Afterward the conjurer
>   usually pretends to find the bird among the audience. As a matter of
>   fact he takes another bird out of his pocket, and by one of the simple
>   dodges of conjuring appears to take it from some one's neck or head,
>   or some other convenient place.
>
> — [*Current Literature*, Volume XIII, May–August, 1893, page 230](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ARQKoHBYRfsC&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Is there a link to the source available?

Comment: @Longshanks Source appears to be [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ARQKoHBYRfsC&pg=PA230&dq=The+vanishing+bird+trick+(which,+I+regret+to+say,+kills+a+great+number+of+canaries)) (or a similar one), which is a compilation of newspaper articles. The paper named is _London Answers_, but I cannot find a newspaper by that name. Though when I searched for "the vanishing bird trick" on https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/, I found that a version of the article was printed in the _Liverpool Echo_ on 25 February 1893.

Comment: It might be worth [edit]ing this into the answer. It might also help to at least explain how you found the note if you can't remember the exact source anymore.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The source is listed. It is Current Literature magazine, June 1893. The article was originally published in "London Answers".

Answer (score 29):

It is based on a real trick, but the sources I provided do not conclusively state if any birds in these acts were ever killed. Only rumors and at least one inquiry, resulting in no substantial proof.

It appears the general nature of the trick in *The Prestige* is a [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_bird_cage) of the real life, **Vanishing Bird Cage**:

> **The vanishing bird cage, also known as the flying birdcage, is a
>   classic parlour magic effect that was invented by French magician
>   Buatier De Kolta.** The trick has also been used by magicians Carl
>   Hertz, Harry Beardmore, Harry Blackstone (Sr. and Jr.) John
>   Mulholland, John Angel, Sabrina Vera, and Tommy Wonder.
>
> The magician displays a bird cage, holding it between both of his
>   hands. The cage is rectangular, about six inches tall by six inches
>   wide by eight inches long, and made of wire on all six sides. Often
>   there is a bird, though in modern performances of the act it is
>   usually fake, inside the cage. The magician will offer the cage for
>   inspection by an audience member, but he will never actually release
>   his grip of it. Then, without covering the cage, the magician makes a
>   sudden motion and the cage (and anything inside) vanishes from sight.
>   **A variation of the trick was featured in the 2006 film The Prestige.**

**More Information:**

> [The Vanishing Birdcage](http://www.themagicdetective.com/2011/02/vanishing-bird-cage-history.html) was a sensation and was also quickly ripped
>   off. **In the Summer of 1875 Harry Kellar is said to have purchased a
>   cage from DeKolta's cousin for $750. Of course this was unauthorized
>   because Buatier never sold cages to anyone.  This cage was probably
>   the very first one outside of DeKolta's act**, but it wouldn't be the
>   last. In fact, Harry Kellar can probably be credited for the deluge of
>   Vanishing Birdcages in America because he sold the secret to a magic
>   dealer in exchange for props. In Europe a letter from Robert Heller to
>   Charles DeVere the french magic dealer shows that the cages were
>   already for sale in December 1875.
>
> **Harry Kellar stirred up a bit of controversy while in Australia over
>   his presentation of "The Flying Cage" as he called it.** Harry Kellar's
>   routine was simple and direct, he counted to three and the cage with a
>   live canary inside would vanish! **A rumor circulated that Kellar was
>   killing a canary every time he presented the effect. An inquiry took
>   place and Kellar proved that was not the case. He showed that he had
>   one bird and one bird only that he had been using for a long while.**
>   But this same controversy would come to haunt other magicians across
>   the globe. **In fact, this controversy was used as a minor plot point in
>   the movie "The Prestige" in which they give a rather fictitious
>   explanation on how the cage works.**

Comment: It's still not clear from this answer though--in these tricks from history, was the bird actually crushed or not? Was Harry Kellar actually telling the truth? Did other magicians kill the bird even if Harry didn't?

Comment: @spacetyper True, but it does at least suggest that there were inquiries, but nothing was ever proven and that The Prestige seems to have taken some large liberties. So far that's all I have been able to find, I'm afraid.

Comment: It would probably be more accurate to make the first sentence "It is based on a real trick, but it's unclear whether there was ever any bird killing involved". The quotes should back up the answer, not be the answer in themselves (note the question specifically asks about the bird killing).

Comment: @DarthLocke I think OP means the trick that's done earlier in the film, where the birdcage collapses inside of a table. In that case it's explicitly shown the bird is crushed.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I originally had that in my post, but edited it out when I added new information that seemed to indicate that birds were thought to be killed, but the inquiry found in Kellar's case, no proof of it. But I will add it back in. :)

Comment: I'm not sure "fictitious" is an appropriate word to describe the explanation for how the trick works. That is, in fact, how the trick works. That there's another trick that works another way doesn't change that.